# What component in .NET would be best to use for a bitmap editor?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, graphics, nintendo

I am working on a game sprite editor for Nintendo development.  The typical tile size the NES stores is in 8x8 pixel format.  I would like to be able to create a solution where you can import / export in binary format.  The binary form is a simply two sets of 8 bytes (16 bytes per tile)  The first byte contains colors 0-1, the second overlays with colors 2-3.

I would like to use .NET to create a very simple graphics editor.  With all the dozens of components to choose from I'm a bit lost.  Ideally, I need an object that can respond to clicks and can be enumerated in a list.

I realize I could probably setup an 8x8 grid of buttons that change color when clicked, but I would like something perhaps more elegant; allowing for larger bitmaps down the road.  I want to minimize overhead, but not get so carried away with design that I turn something simple into a behemoth.

I would greatly appreciate some tips as how to very simply implement a pixel / bitmap editor in .NET.  I can go with either C# or VB with this project.

Thanks,

EDIT: To clarify, this would be a Win Form application.

Comment: Metro? WinForms? WPF? Silverlight? Windows Phone? ASP.Net? MonoTouch?

Comment: Sorry, this would be a WinForms application.

Comment: You might start by looking at the Bitmap typr in System.Drawing.

Comment: @MikeCheel I would actually recommend away from using that class and towards using the WPF bitmap classes, the `System.Drawing` classes have major issues and are based on GDI whereas the WPF ones are based on WIC and work much better.

Comment: I couldn't speak to that but I used them the other day with no problems at all.

Comment: I love nuggets check this out : http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=bitmap